# In Devil May Cry 5, how does Urizen defeat Dante, Nero, Trish, and Lady in their first battle?

Tags: devil-may-cry

In *Devil May Cry 5*, Urizen defeats Dante, Nero, Trish, and Lady in their first battle. But after the second and third battle with Dante, Urizen is beaten by Dante while he can defeat Nero in their second battle.

It doesn't make any sense because Urizen is half of Vergil, so his power level must be 50% of Vergil's but he manages to defeat heroes in their first battle. Urizen kicks everyone's ass.

How does he defeat the heroes in their first battle?

Comment: @W.Are actually we do allow questions on japanese games so long as it's about the plot. especially when they do have tie ins with anime and manga in which [there is an upcoming Manga about V](https://www.destructoid.com/devil-may-cry-5-tritagonist-v-will-host-his-own-manga-series-545913.phtml)

Comment: keep in mind that Vergil chose to embrace his demonic side while Dante chose to embrace his human side and it possibly this choice that we see most of the time Dante being at a disadvantage against Vergil in 3 and in the 1st game when Vergil was Neo Angelo from what i understand the first few times Dante would have lost had it not been for Neo Angelo fleeing when Mundus's control over him was shaken. i don't know about Nero's abilities but Lady from what i recall didn't have much of a chance against Vergil in 3 anyway

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in Nico's reports. She talks about how Urizen bound himself to the Qliphoth, a tree predating the Underworld itself. According to Trish, it was once used by Mundus to conquer the Underworld. Urizen, already boasting Vergil's demonic power, was now bolstered by a primordial power source as well as the Yamato.

Ive found it out from [here](https://devilmaycry.fandom.com/wiki/Urizen) under file section you can see **Nico Enemy Report - Urizen**